# MySQL - Help needed on how to get the Max of Ave()

Tags: mysql

Consider a table storing the marks obtained by student in five course, physics, chemistry, mathematics, history and philosophy in comma separated form.

[image: table marks]

[image: Interpreted as]

```
table name : marks 
----------   ---------------
student_id |  marks
-----------  ---------------
23         |  63,85,89,70,76
-----------  ---------------
```

Write a query to determine the id of the student who has the highest average in Physics, Chemistry and Mathematics. 
Assume that the marks are all stored as two digit numbers.

My Approach -

```
select student_id, max(ave) as AV
from ( SELECT student_id, AVG(LEFT(marks , 3)) ave FROM  marks group by student_id) 
marks
group by student_id 
order by "AV" desc limit 1 ;
```

ooutput:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
7
69
*************************** 2. row ***************************
12
87
*************************** 3. row ***************************
18
77
*************************** 4. row ***************************
22
76
*************************** 5. row ***************************
29
89
*************************** 6. row ***************************
32
98
*************************** 7. row ***************************
57
95
*************************** 8. row ***************************
59
90
*************************** 9. row ***************************
78
75
*************************** 10. row ***************************
83
67
*************************** 11. row ***************************
88
57
*************************** 12. row ***************************
98
59
```

How do I display the student_id whose marks is the highest ?

Comment: Please provide textual information as text, not as a link to a picture of text or as picture of text. In case of database related questions, showing tables is not helpful, please provide database structure and content in a reusable way, i.e. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: For making your posts more readable and clearer, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

You can get the average in  in Physics, Chemistry and Mathematics with:

```
(substr(marks, 1, 2) + substr(marks, 4, 2) + substr(marks, 7, 2)) / 3
```

so your query can be:

```
select student_id,
  (substr(marks, 1, 2) + substr(marks, 4, 2) + substr(marks, 7, 2)) / 3 avgmarks
from marks  
order by avgmarks desc
limit 1;
```

if you are not interested in ties.
If you want ties:

```
select student_id 
from marks
where (substr(marks, 1, 2) + substr(marks, 4, 2) + substr(marks, 7, 2)) / 3 = (
  select max((substr(marks, 1, 2) + substr(marks, 4, 2) + substr(marks, 7, 2)) / 3)
  from marks
);
```

In Mysql 8.0+ you can use `RANK()` window function:

```
select student_id
from (
  select student_id,
    rank() over (
      order by (substr(marks, 1, 2) + substr(marks, 4, 2) + substr(marks, 7, 2)) / 3 desc
    ) rnk                                                               
  from marks  
) t 
where t.rnk = 1
```

Comment: All the queries are syntactically correct as you can see here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iFzpCpcNp1JqermuvKSbiM/1 What is the error?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(substr(marks, 1, 2) + substr(marks, 4, 2) + substr(marks, 7, 2)) / 3 avgmarks)
' at line 2

Comment: Did you run the 1st expression in my answer only? It is not a query. Use any of the 3 queries.

Comment: I ran the 1st query -
select student_id,
  (substr(marks, 1, 2) + substr(marks, 4, 2) + substr(marks, 7, 2)) / 3 avgmarks
from marks  
order by avgmarks desc
limit 1;

Comment: It runs fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iFzpCpcNp1JqermuvKSbiM/3

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
Its very simple and direct.

```
select student_id from marks 
where marks = 
(select max(avg_value) from 
( SELECT AVG(LEFT(marks , 3)) avg_value FROM marks GROUP BY student_id)
marks
)
```

This code will output the student_id from the table whose MAX(AVG(P,C,M)) .
You can verify the same by removing student_id and replace it with a * in the first line of code.